# How can I delete duplicate entries in keyboard shortcuts services?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, services

I have several duplicate entries in the keyboard shortcuts services. 
I want to delete the duplicate entries, and right clicked and clicked `show in Finder` to find the location of these. But it leads to `Applications` folder.

So I tried find these location manually, but I could not.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom services can be found in `~/Library/Services`.

If showing the service in the finder led you to the Applications folder it's a service that came bundled with an app. These should be defined in that app's `Info.plist`.

You can access it by right clicking on that application in the Finder, selecting `Show Package Contents` and navigating to `Contents`.
Once you've opened the file look for the `Services` key. Expanding it will show you all services that come bundled with that app. Deleting a service's key *might* remove its entry from `Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services`. Be sure to make a backup of the .plist file first, in case something goes wrong and you want to roll back the changes.

> Note that you might need extra software (like Xcode) to open `.plist` files.

Comment: Your answer could helped. I have found that uncheck and rechecking the services option "in the LaTeXit.app" could solve duplicate services problem